# React Native: Why is Expo-AV not playing audio?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, audio

I'm attempting to build an app that acts as a soundboard and can play different sounds when different buttons are pressed. I expected the audio to play but instead, I got an error that stated:

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1): TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_expoAv.Audio.sound.createAsync')
playSound$
```

This is my code:

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { Feather } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { Audio } from "expo-av";

// project made in yarn
// yarn start
// yarn add

export default function App() {
  const [sound, setSound] = useState("");

  const playSound = async () => {
    console.log("Loading Sound");
    const { sound } = await Audio.sound.createAsync(
      require("./assets/Ayo.mp3")
    );
    setSound(sound);

    console.log("playing sound");
    await sound.playAsync();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    return sound
      ? () => {
          console.log("unloading the sound");
          sound.unloadAsync();
        }
      : undefined;
  }, [sound]);
  // run useEffect whenever sound state changes

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>SoundGround</Text>

      <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={playSound}>
          <Feather name="arrow-left" style={styles.iconStyle} />
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity onPress={playSound}>
          <Feather name="arrow-right" style={styles.iconStyle} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  iconStyle: {
    fontSize: 100,
  },
});
```

So far, I've tried adding a try/catch block, using different audio formats. I think the error has to do with state not being assigned before it is used to play something - but I'm not sure.

Comment: The code block is given on the documentation also doesn't work on my physical device through expo, could this be an issue on my own physical device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement `useRef` instead of `useState` to stop re-rendering!

This worked for me very well.

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { Feather } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { Audio } from "expo-av";

// project made in yarn
// yarn start
// yarn add

export default function App() {
  const sound = useRef(new Audio.Sound());

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => sound.current.unloadAsync();
  }, []);

  const playSound = async () => {
    console.log("Loading Sound");

    await sound.current.createAsync(require("./assets/Ayo.mp3"));

    console.log("playing sound");

    const checkLoaded = await sound.current.getStatusAsync();
    if (checkLoaded.isLoaded === true) {
      console.log("Error in Loading mp3");
    } else {
      await sound.current.playAsync();
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>SoundGround</Text>

      <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => playSound()}>
          <Feather name="arrow-left" style={styles.iconStyle} />
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => playSound()}>
          <Feather name="arrow-right" style={styles.iconStyle} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  iconStyle: {
    fontSize: 100,
  },
});
```

Comment: the line `await sound.current.createAsync` seems to have an issue, resolved by: `const { sound: playbackObject } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(require(".../path")); sound.current = playbackObject`